# can't read SD card on 2016 MacBook running Sierra

Tags: usb, macos, sd-card

I have had my MacBook just a few months so I'm very much a newbie with it and the OS.

My mac has only one port that's the charging port I bought the USB adapter but when I put a thumb drive in, it doesn't show up anywhere.

I've scanned the internet for answers but haven't any luck. I have all the finder options checked. So now I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Have you tested the thumb drive with another computer? - There's a possibility that either the drive or the adapter is broken. Try opening System Report and check if anything shows up on the USB bus when you plug them in. It is supposed to just show up in Finder when you plugin the drive.

Comment: I did just try the adapter in my Sony and it also didn't work. So I'm guessing the adapter is probably too old. So I'm on the hunt for a new one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, we've solved the puzzle! - I've converted my comment to an answer as it solved your question. Please mark it as answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First test the thumb drive with another computer. There's a possibility that either the drive or the adapter is broken.

Open System Report and check if anything shows up on the USB bus when you plug them in.

It is also supposed to just show up in Finder when you plugin the drive.